# Array inside list object, how to handle?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have these two classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Output { get; set; }
    public int Wharf { get; set; }
    public int PartOf { get; set; }
    public int[] Product { get; set; }
    public int[] Quantity { get; set; }
    public int[] Storage { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Order obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (ID == obj.ID);
    }
}

public class RawOrderData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Output { get; set; }
    public int Wharf { get; set; }
    public int PartOfID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Every order in the system is in the form as class `Order`, the array is used when there are more than one product in the order. 
`RawOrderData` is created from a JSON string where every product in the order have its own object. I want to create a `List<Order>` where every order gets its own object in the list so there not are several orders with same order id when order contains more than one product.

```
// raw data is here the JSON string
rawdatalist = serializer.Deserialize<List<RawOrderData>> (rawdata);

// Convert raw objects to List<Order>, list of orders 
List<Order> orders = new List<Order> ();
orders = ConvertRawOrderToList (rawdatalist);

private List<Order> ConvertRawOrderToList(List<RawOrderData> datalist)
{
    List<Order> orders = new List<Order> ();

    foreach (RawOrderData dataobj in datalist) 
    {
        // Check if order exists in list
        if (orders.Contains(new Order () {ID = dataobj.ID}))
        {
            // Order exists, add more products
            // CODE HERE?
        } else {
            // order not existing, add new order to list
            short storage = GetStorageArea(dataobj.ProductID);
            orders.Add (new Order () {ID = dataobj.ID, Output = dataobj.Output, Wharf = dataobj.Wharf, PartOf = dataobj.PartOfID, Product = dataobj.ProductID, Quantity = dataobj.Quantity});
        }
    }
    return orders;
}
```

Do I think correct with the `ConvertRawOrderToList` method? The problem is I don't know what to write in `// CODE HERE?`. When there is array inside the list-object I'm confused.

I'm also wondering how to access all values in the `List<Order>` orders.

The information to `Storage[]` is created from another method that have product ID as input.

Comment: Note that `orders.Contains(new Order ())` will _never_ be true since you haven;t overridden `Equals` on the `Order` class.

Comment: I added that now, does it work that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a "flattened" collection of objects that you want to group into `Order`s.  If that's the case, a basic Linq projection would be simplest:

```
var orders = datalist.GroupBy(o => o.ID)
                     .Select(g => new Order {
                           ID       = g.Key,
                           Output   = g.First().Output,
                           Wharf    = g.First().Wharf,
                           PartOf   = g.First().PartOf,
                           Product  = g.Select(o => o.Product).ToArray(),
                           Quantity = g.Select(o => o.Product).ToArray(),  
                         })
                     .ToList();
```

Then you don't need to worry about overriding `Equals` (at least not for this purpose).

> Where would I add the method for adding Storage also?

Since your `GetStorageArea` function takes a single ProductID you need to pass the product IDs to that function:

```
var orders = datalist.GroupBy(o => o.ID)
                     .Select(g => new Order {
                           ID       = g.Key,
                           Output   = g.First().Output,
                           Wharf    = g.First().Wharf,
                           PartOf   = g.First().PartOf,
                           Product  = g.Select(o => o.Product).ToArray(),
                           Quantity = g.Select(o => o.Product).ToArray(),  
                           Storage  = g.Select(o => GetStorageArea(o.Product)).ToArray()
                         })
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: +1`  on a related note, it looks like the OP might want to make a `Product` class which contains a `ProductId`,  a  `Quantity` a `Storage`

Comment: Where would I add the method for adding Storage also? "Storage = GetStorage(ProductID)"